# overlapping Views during Push transition

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, background-image

I have a `storyboard` in which i am pushing one view on top of another view in the navigation controller.(Simple push Segue). I am setting the background of the new view in the `viewDidLoad` method and using the following code to do so.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome_bg_pattern"] ];
```

But during the push animation form one view to the other view i can see both the views overlapping. Can some body can guide me how i can set the background so that i don't have that problem.

Here are the attach imaged

first View
[image]

During push Transition. here you can see both the vies are overlapped this will not happen if i just simple set a `redColor` as `background` color of the view

[image]

Second View
[image]

I have also tried by setting the background image in the `viewWillAppear`

Any help will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of set background image of `self.view` like

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome_bg_pattern"] ];
```

set background image in `UIImageView` with set proper frame and add `UIImageView` as subView of `self.view`.